# docker CMD array syntax for double quotes inside double quotes for gunicorn

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using docker and gunicorn for my python application.
I am starting gunicorn as below:

**CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers 2", "--threads 2", "--bind 0.0.0.0:8000", "--preload", ""main:create_app()""]**

But getting error as wrong syntax, because of last element i.e. (**""main:create_app()""**).
As given in gunicorn documentation, I am trying to use below form:

```
def create_app():
    app = FrameworkApp()
    ...
    return app
```

```
$ gunicorn --workers=2 'test:create_app()'
```

I Also tried single quotes as **"'main:create_app()'"**, But this also failed.

What I am missing?

Comment: `--workers` and `2` are two separate arguments.

Comment: And don't try to insert literal quotes in place of syntactic quotes. When you run `'test:create_app()'` in a shell, the `'`s are removed before `gunicorn` is started; they're consumed _by the shell_, not by gunicorn itself.

Comment: (`"--workers=2"` with an `=` is valid as one argument, or `"--workers", "2"` as two arguments; but you can't do `"--workers 2"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct usage is:

```
RUN ["gunicorn", "--workers", "2", "--threads", "2", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--preload", "main:create_app()"]
```

- Everywhere you have an unquoted space between two shell arguments in the original/working shell command, you need to split into separate elements in your JSON list. That means `--workers` and `2` are two different strings, instead of being one string `--workers 2`; the same goes for everywhere else you have an argument and an argument-option paired.
- Syntactic shell quotes, like the quotes around `'main:create_app()'`, are instructions **to the shell** that symbols like `()` should not be treated as shell syntax. Because there *is* no shell here, those instructions are unnecessary. Just use `"main:create_app()"` as a simple JSON string, with only JSON quotes; no literal quotes are necessary or appropriate.

---

If you have questions in the future about how to convert a simple command to a JSON string, you can ask `jq` to do it for you:

```json
$ jq -cn --args '$ARGS.positional' -- gunicorn --workers 2 --threads 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --preload 'main:create_app()'
["gunicorn","--workers","2","--threads","2","--bind","0.0.0.0:8000","--preload","main:create_app()"]
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, for quick reply. It worked.